# Condition to get specific cell value in ultragrid

Tags: c#, infragistics

I am trying to make some cells readonly on specific condition(flag). But i'm having problem to set the exact condition. I have a not null bit column and trying to set condition on its value.
Here is my code :

```
private void grdOtherItemsInfo_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        UltraGridBand band;
        try
        {
            band = e.Layout.Bands[0];

            band.ColHeaderLines = 2;
            foreach (UltraGridRow row in **can't find right option**)
            {
                if (row.Cells[OtherItemStoreRequisitionForBatchChild.IsAutoDispense].Value.ToString() == "1")
                {
                    band.Columns[OtherItemStoreRequisitionForBatchChild.IsAutoDispense].CellActivation = Activation.ActivateOnly;
                    band.Columns[OtherItemStoreRequisitionForBatchChild.IndentedUOM].CellActivation = Activation.ActivateOnly;
                    band.Columns[OtherItemStoreRequisitionForBatchChild.IndentedQty].CellActivation = Activation.ActivateOnly;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: grdOtherItemsInfo.Rows ?

Comment: @Steve grdOtherItemsInfo.Rows wasn't working because of having more than 1 index of e.layout.bands that i didn't mention here. Anyway thanks a lot. I got a solution that I added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (UltraGridRow row in grdOtherItemsInfo.Rows)
        {
            foreach (UltraGridRow urow in grdChemicalItemInfo.Rows[row.Index].ChildBands[0].Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(urow.Cells[OtherItemStoreRequisitionForBatchChild.IsAutoDispense].Value))
                {
                    foreach (UltraGridCell col in urow.Cells)
                    {
                        col.Activation = Activation.ActivateOnly;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The band has no rows property. If you need to iterate through all the rows you need to call grdOtherItemsInfo.Rows. You may use code like this:

```
private void grdOtherItemsInfo_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    UltraGridBand band;
    try
    {
        band = e.Layout.Bands[0];

        band.ColHeaderLines = 2;

        // Rows collection of the grid contains the rows in Band[0] or the top level of GroupByRows
        foreach (UltraGridRow row in this.grdOtherItemsInfo.Rows)
        {
            // Check if the row is DataRow, otherwise you will get an exception when you call Cell property of not data row
            if (row.IsDataRow)
            {
                // Cashing the cell so not taking it twice
                UltraGridCell cell = row.Cells[OtherItemStoreRequisitionForBatchChild.IsAutoDispense];
                if (cell.Value.ToString() == "1")
                {
                    // Setting the cells' Activation will set each cell its own activation
                    // If you set it to the column all the cells in the column will have same activation
                    cell.Activation = Activation.ActivateOnly;
                    row.Cells[OtherItemStoreRequisitionForBatchChild.IndentedUOM].Activation = Activation.ActivateOnly;
                    row.Cells[OtherItemStoreRequisitionForBatchChild.IndentedQty].Activation = Activation.ActivateOnly;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: ...
    }
}
```

Note that in your code you are going through all the rows and you are setting the column CellActivation depending on some row's cell value. In the result of this the CellActivation may change several times but in the end it will depend on the value of the cell in the last row. Setting the CellActivation on the column force all the cells in that column to have same CellActivatio. If you need different CellActivation for each cell in a column you need to set the Activation property of each individual cell - this is what the code I send you do.

Check also [this](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/WinGrid_Loop_Through_the_Entire_Grid.html) link showing how to iterate grid's rows

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already did it yesterday. I was facing problems because of having more than 1 index of e.layout.bands that i didn't mention here. so grdOtherItemsInfo.Rows was not working. I got a solution that I added as an answer.